# Getting twitter #hashtag posts in C++

Tags: c++, twitter, curl, hashtag

I have seen some libraries around (like twitcurl) for a twitter / C++ interface, but twitcurl (or any that I have seen) don't support hashtag retrieval. What I want to do is check for the latest hashtag of a certain string, then display this on the screen. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the RSS feed for your twitter hashtag search, using http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23gobarsoom (replacing "gobarsoom" with your hashtag). Then use an RSS library like the [Windows RSS Platform (Microsoft Feed APIs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684701.aspx) to parse it.